# Remove duplicate values across a few columns but keep rows

Tags: r, dplyr, duplicates

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
dat <- data.frame(id=1:6,
                  z_1=c(100,290,38,129,0,290),
                  z_2=c(20,0,0,0,0,290),
                  z_3=c(0,0,38,0,0,98),
                  z_4=c(0,0,38,127,38,78),
                  z_5=c(23,0,25,0,0,98),
                  z_6=c(100,0,25,127,0,9))
```

`dat`

```
  id z_1 z_2 z_3 z_4 z_5 z_6
1  1 100 20  0   0   23  100
2  2 290  0  0   0   0   0
3  3  38  0  38  38  25  25
4  4 129  0  0   127 0   127
5  5   0  0  0   38  0   0
6  6 290 290 98  78  98  9
```

I want to remove duplicate values of `z_x` across each row, replacing any duplicates with either a `0` or `NA`, but leaving the rows & columns intact (ie not dropping any). The 0s here do not count as duplicates, they are missing values. Duplicate values within a column are ok. My ideal output would look like this:

```
   id z_1 z_2 z_3 z_4 z_5 z_6
1  1  100 20  0   0   23  0
2  2  290 0   0   0   0   0
3  3  38  0   0   0   25  0
4  4  129 0   0   127 0   0
5  5   0  0   0   38  0   0
6  6  290 0   98  78  0   9
```

I don't really care what order the values within the `z_x`s appear in, so it's fine if they get moved around. Is there an efficient way to do this, preferably in some tidyverse way? I know I can pivot longer and drop duplicate rows, but my dataset is very large and I'm looking for a way to do this without pivoting.

Comment: I'm struggling to think of a way that would be quicker than pivoting longer and dropping duplicates. Even if you don't explicitly pivot, you're still going to have to either split/loop over each row identifier, which will usually be super slow anyway if you've got an enormous number of rows.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Base R way using `apply` :

```
cols <- grep('z_\\d+', names(dat))
dat[cols] <- t(apply(dat[cols], 1, function(x)  replace(x, duplicated(x), 0)))

#  id z_1 z_2 z_3 z_4 z_5 z_6
#1  1 100  20   0   0  23   0
#2  2 290   0   0   0   0   0
#3  3  38   0   0   0  25   0
#4  4 129   0   0 127   0   0
#5  5   0   0   0  38   0   0
#6  6 290   0  98  78   0   9
```

`tidyverse` way without reshaping can be done using `pmap` :

```
library(tidyverse)

dat %>%
  mutate(result = pmap(select(., matches('z_\\d+')), ~{
    x <- c(...)
    replace(x, duplicated(x), 0)
    })) %>%
  select(id, result) %>%
  unnest_wider(result)
```

Since tests performed by @thelatemail suggests reshaping is a better option than handling the data rowwise you might want to consider it.

```
dat %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = matches('z_\\d+')) %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(value = replace(value, duplicated(value), 0)) %>%
  pivot_wider()
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, thank you! My dataframe has millions of rows but only about 30 of these columns to remove duplicates from - do you know if one of these methods will be faster than the other?

Comment: @Ian - the `pmap` solution is much slower than even the basic `apply` loop by a quick test.

Comment: From a quick test, going long then wide again on 2M records is < 1 second, `apply` was 15 seconds, `pmap` I killed after a minute without it finishing.

Comment: I tested using a slightly different approach to take distinct `id/value` pairs - I think that should be speedier than needing to group, e.g.: `dat %>% pivot_longer(starts_with("z_")) %>% distinct(id, value, .keep_all=TRUE) %>% pivot_wider(values_fill=0)`

Answer (score 1):

This solution isn't tidyverse, but hopefully is sufficiently simple.

The `duplicated()` function does what you want. You can use `apply()` function to feed `duplicated()` your data by row.

```
dat[t(apply(dat, MARGIN = 1, duplicated))] <- 0
```